# Proyectos reutilizable en angular

Tags: angular, angular9

Tengo dos proyectos de angular por separado, cada uno de ellos tienen los mismos modelos, services y enums.
Me puse a investigar si era posible realizar por medio de librerias como gradle separarlo y hacerlo reutilizable, pero no he encontrado algo como tal o algun articulo donde especifique lo que necesito; Si se modifica algun services o modelo se debe realizar en ambos proyecto. ¿Cual es la mejor manera de manejar este tipo de proyectos?

Comment: La pregunta está buscando opiniones y por ello le auguro un futuro corto. Como comentario, puedo decir que puedes pensar en crear componentes angular reutilizables, dejarlos disponibles en algún repo (Nexus?) e importarlos donde los necesites.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar Angular CLI para generar una librería. Copias los archivos que necesitas y posteriormente los puedes publicar como un paquete npm y desde ahí ir actualizando la librería y su referencia en tus proyectos.
También puedes importar directamente a tu proyecto.

https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#refactoring-parts-of-an-app-into-a-library

Comment: Gracias por el link, voy a leer sobre eso y ver como me va